# In data provider how to set the sorting both asc and desc .But initially the data display in desc order

Tags: php, yii

I tried this code,But the data only display in desc order.but i cant change in asc order.

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Holiday', array(
                        'criteria' => array(
                        'order'  => 'Date DESC',
                        ),
                        'pagination'=>array(
                        'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->controller->module->user_page_size,
                        ),
                    ));
```

Comment: Are you saying that `Date ASC` does not work as opposed to `Date DESC`? because I'm not able to replicate that.

Comment: Yes,the date asc order is not work

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Holiday', array(
                        'criteria' => array(
                        'order'  => 'ASC',
                        'order by' => 'Date'
                        ),
                        'pagination'=>array(
                        'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->controller->module->user_page_size,
                        ),
                    ));
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work.its show Property "CDbCriteria.orderby" is not defined. error

Comment: I tried this code.Its working for me.$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Holiday',
                    array(
                        'sort' => array('defaultOrder' => 'Date DESC')
                    ));

Comment: In data provider when i click the click the date header its working in asc order.also.first its not working in asc order.

Comment: what is the type of field in DB?

Answer (score 0):

You **should not** be using terms like `Date` for your field names which are reserved for internal purposes on most SQL platforms. Check your SQL server documentation on reserved words. [I am assuming you are using data from a db, of course!]

If your date field is named 'd_date', you could use the following to sort your grid with a `'d_date'` column, with a descending default.

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Holiday',array(
    'sort' => array(
        'd_date' => array(
            'asc' => 'd_date asc',
            'desc' => 'd_date desc',
        ),
        'defaultOrder' => 'd_date desc',
    ),
));
```